# PostgreSQL - hiding tables from user

Tags: postgresql

I wonder if there is a possibility to hide tables from a certain user, not just revoking access to them.

Basically what needs to be done is to grant a user read-only access to the DB, but hide some tables from him.

I tried to revoke all privileges from schema public but to no avail.

Comment: Related: [How to prevent a login from 'listing' a table or view definition in PostgreSQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/177266/88191) or [PostgreSQL 9.5: Permission to deny functions body](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/177266/88191)

Answer (score 2):

So far you can not hide [Postgres System Catalogs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalogs.html). Meaning you can not hide metadata.

The user can still see the structure, but can not access them if not granted access.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to grant specific permissions to specific users you can use VIEWS.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_views.htm